# Returning object as function result

Tags: c++

Can I return string that was created in `ggg` function to `h` variable or it might be already destroyed?

```
std::string ggg()
{

    std::string g = "blabla" ;
    return g;

}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    std:string h = ggg();
}
```

Comment: Why not starting your compiler (or an online compiler) and [check yourself](http://ideone.com/GVhFbN)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Just because it works doesn't confirm that it's standards conforming (but it is in this case).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: If he tried it with a reference or pointer, chances are it would seemingly work as well.

Comment: To the OP: your code would be undefined behaviour only if `ggg` returned a reference or pointer. Returning by value is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. Value will be copied.

*Edited.*
Modern clever compilers can also use move semantics, you can read about this in other answers :)

Comment: _"Value will be copied"_ ... or moved!

Comment: or the copy may be elided.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, it won't be destroyed it would be either be copied or moved. As to what of the two will happen it depends on the context that `ggg()` is being evoked.

For example if you call it like below:

```
std:string h = ggg();
```

The returned `std::string` from `ggg()` is going to be elided/moved.

If you call it like below:

```
std::string h;
...
h = ggg();
```

The returned value is going to be copied to `h`.

Answer (score 1):

You could returned without any problem, it's correct code.

In `C++98` the recommendation was **not do this with complex or big object** because would be copied and have performance hit (the extra copy). In the specific case in question the copy almost sure would be elided by the compiler (see [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) to understand why, *note:* really old compiler don't have this optimization). But in more complex code (eg: more complex function body, more return statement, etc...), even returning the same type (`std::string`) the optimization could not be apply (this in performance sensitive code is a kill).

In `C++11` is much better if the compiler could be sure that the value would not be used anymore (eg: would be destroyed by out of scope, like this case and many other cases), would optimized and the value is moved (*normally more performant that copy*, **note:** sometimes copy is as performant as move, *eg:* a class with only POD members). In the specific case in question of returning a `std::string`, the move would be (in most implementations of STL) a copy of a couple of pointers.

In the specific case in question most probably would be the same code generated in `C++98` and `C++11`.

In `C++11` this case if perfect example of [Move Semantic](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

Comment: Of course, even a modern C++98 compiler would apply [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) in a case like this, eliminating the copy altogether.

Comment: Yes this specific case would be OK, for that, i specify `complex or big objects` and don't reference the case in the question explicitly. With a more complex function body and multiple return statements, would be other history, even returning the same type.

Comment: -1. In C++98 it was and is NOT the recommendation to avoid this with big objects. Quite the contrary; Scott Meyers in "Effective C++", if you count that as a famous recommendation, explicitly warned about futile attempts to avoid copies when copies are needed. And as Fred Larson correctly says, RVO has existed long before C++11.

Comment: Yes of course Scott Meyer is a extremely good recommendation, but you are taking about specific cases `when copies are needed`, when copies are needed it's the same C++98 and C++11, my thinking is that Scott Meyer is warning that the `Move Semantic` would not be used without careful knowledge of the problem to solve and the undiscriminated use is bad. But I don't think he is recommending return by value as a general recommendation, especially when he and `Andrei Alexandrescu` talk about that in Going Native the last 2 year and even in C++11 recommend careful thinking.

Comment: `(continued)` (more in performance sensitive code), even in C++11 the `Move Semantic` don't solve all the problem (this is one of the uses of `std::move`, to enforce the move, if exist), solve a lot of problem, it's really a much, much better place that C++98, but sometimes the compiler is not certain that a move could be generated. RVO and NRVO as I understand was like a patch to alleviate the need for `Move Semantic` and solve various case (like in the question) but it's a more fragile optimization that `Move Semantic`